# Did the McCallisters bother to call home?

Tags: plot-explanation, home-alone

In "Home Alone", wouldn't Kevin's Parents try to call home? I don't remember them trying to call the house to check up on Kevin. I know the power lines were down due to a tree branch the night before but they must of been fixed in 1 day because when Kevin called 911 it was working and when some of the other Family Members called neighbors there were Answering Machines so the phone lines must have been working again but the McCallisters didn't know about it.

Comment: Except the dad called the neighbor and left a message from Paris. Why wouldn't he just call home and they were only gone a little over two days as they explain when the mom refuses to wait for the flight the family comes home on.

Answer (score 11):

**The phone lines were down due to the storm.**

This is addressed in the dialog. From [the script](http://www.godamongdirectors.com/scripts/homealone.txt):

> As Kay enters the van, the power man approaches her. "Mame, I just want you to know that your power is fixed, **but your phone lines are a mess**. it's going to take Ma bell a couple of days to patch it up, especially around
> the holidays."

When he calls the cops near the end of the movie, this is several days later, so it is reasonable to assume that the phone lines have been fixed by then. His parents did not continually try to call throughout the movie; they were too busy just trying to get home, and they didn't know when phone service would be restored again.

Now, there is also an often talked about plot hole that Kevin orders a pizza, and he shouldn't have been able to do that if the phones were down. This is likely just a plot hole in the movie, but there are also possible explanations for it, such as that it was only the long distance lines that weren't working, while [local calls would still work](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/home-alone-plot-hole-has-logical-explanation_us_560be46de4b0dd850309e9bc).

Comment: the power going out is the reason they all get up late too, and knock on effect of this is Keven being left HOME ALONE